# mySQL : Select "variable" as "variable2" from table

Tags: mysql, variables, select

I am using this line of code in mySQL :

```
select sum(amount) as 'October_Amount' from table
where month(date)=month(now());
```

and I want to get the current month in the "Month_Amount" string (e.g. "October_Amount"). I tried this one:

```
select sum(amount) as monthname(curdate()) from table
where month(date)=month(now());
```

but it did not work. `(monthname(now()))` or `(monthname(curdate()))` are strings so it should work. I tried many versions and no suggestion found.

Comment: Can you clarify why it did not work?
Do you get an error? What is the error?
Or it returns with no data?

Comment: @SpyrosK Εδώ : Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(now()) from table where month(date)=month(now())' at line 1

Comment: You cannot dynamically change the column name in the statement, you would need to use prepared statements to alter the actual query (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use column name dynamic you can use PREPARED STATEMENTS like this

```
SET @date = DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE(),'%M');
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT SUM(amount) AS "', @date, '_Amount" FROM table where MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW())');
PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @query;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;
```

Comment: there is no need for prepared statements, if you are making the query with any programming language, just make the query dinamically.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select sum(amount), monthname(curdate()) from table
where month(date)=month(now());
```

or this:

```
select sum(amount), CONCAT('AMOUNT_', monthname(curdate())) from table
where month(date)=month(now());
```

Comment: @bluntT This is not what I want to get. The monthname(curdate()) works apparently. But it does not work when I put it in the expression after "AS".

Comment: @ApoloRadomer you cannot set the column name dinamically. I assumed that was a mistake in your query.

Comment: @BluntT There is now way to set the column_name dynamically? oO

Comment: @ApoloRadomer the only way to set the column name dynamically is to create the column name in code (PHP for example) and append it to the query dinamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  CONCAT(sum(amount), '_', month(now())) from table where
month(date)=month(now());
```

Comment: The 'monthname(curdate())' works. The problem is that it does not work after the SELECT AS.